# Lightbox2 - How to add a description to the open image (not caption)

Tags: lightbox2

I'm having some trouble adding text to the open lightbox image using HTML and CSS. I thought it was a caption but eventually figured out that's not it. Here's myy code:

```
<a href="img/portfolio/greenleavesbranding.png" data-lightbox="roadtrip">  <img class="artworkimg" src="img/portfolio/greenleavesthumb.png">
```

Currently theres no CSS as everything I've tried has failed so I've gotten rid of the code I don't need. But the text needs to be white and changed to my current font family.

I'm not an advanced coder, I know enough to modify HTML templates and add CSS.

[Here's a screenshot - the red X is where I want the text to be.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArrpR.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: Edit: I will also need to add text links in the description, will this be problematic once the original issue is sorted?